# Convert table rows to columns (and cast to different types)

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm currently working on a Wordpress site where I store meta values for post types. The meta values are stored in a table called `wp_postmeta` as a key/value combos. This means that multiple meta values for a single post are stored over different rows.

I've been somehow successfully able to transpose the rows as columns using the following query:

```
SELECT post_id,
MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key='store_lng' THEN meta_value END ) AS lng,
MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key='store_lat' THEN meta_value END ) AS lat
FROM wp_postmeta GROUP BY post_id
```

Here you can see that I'm loading the Longitude and Latitude values from the `wp_postmeta` table and see as output the `post_id`, `lng` and `lat`.

I'm sort of happy with this part however, it gets a little more complicated. I want to to some calculations on the `lng` and `lat` values to see if they're in a certain range. The problem is that the meta values in the `wp_postmeta` table are stored as text. Ideally I'd like my query to look something like this:

```
SELECT post_id,
MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key='store_lng' THEN meta_value END ) AS lng,
MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key='store_lat' THEN meta_value END ) AS lat
FROM wp_postmeta GROUP BY post_id
WHERE
(lat BETWEEN %f AND %f)
AND
(lng BETWEEN %f AND %f)
```

Where `%f` is of course the `lng` and `lat` range which I calculate before hand.

So, the question is; How can I get the `lng` and `lat` values to cast to a float so I can perform the BETWEEN operator on them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `where` clause is applied before the `group by`.  The `where` filter will check each row for matching both a `lat` and `lng` condition:

```
post_id    meta_key    meta_value
1          store_lng   1.0
1          store_lat   2.0
2          store_lng   3.0
```

Since each row only defines a single property, no row can satisfy both conditions, and the query should always return an empty set.

To apply filters after `group by`, use `having`.  For example:

```
....
FROM    wp_postmeta 
GROUP   BY post_id
HAVING  lat BETWEEN %f AND %f AND lng BETWEEN %f AND %f
```

The group of rows for a single post can contain both a `lat` and `lng`.

MySQL should convert the text to float automatically for the conversion.  If not, you can "force" a double with `(1.0 * lat)`.